# Create a dynamic ilnk in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, I have a form and I want to use the selected value of one of the inputs in a link. How do I accomplish this? Thanks

```
<%t= f.text_field :studen_id, placeholder: 'Type Here ', class: 'form-control load_assets' %>
<% link_to 'Show Details', .... %>
```

## Jquery Code

```
  .
  .
  .
 }).on('typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted',
   #code that sets the value of link
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# view
<% link_to 'Show details', '#', class: 'dynamic-link' %>

# javascript
.on('typeahead:selected typeahead:autocompleted', function() {
  url = $(this).val() // assuming this is the vaule of the input
  $('.dynamic-link').attr('href', url) // set required data
});
```